# Slow fade option with an LM3914 IC

Tags: voltage, led-strip

I have been researching the best circuit design for LED VU meters and a popular choice is the LM3914/5/6 series of IC's. You can find may videos of these chips used in videos on YouTube, as an example. Many of these designs from other people show a very fast LED response to audio, however the data sheet provided (pg. 21) says there is the option for "slow"- Fade bar or dot display (doubles resolution). I am having trouble finding how I could 'slow' the response, as mentioned in the data sheet using these IC's. Hopefully someone can clarify.

Comment: Try a small 0.1 to 10 uf capacitor in parallel with the input. That should smooth out the incoming signal and provide a longer light time. This is an educated guess though.

Answer (score 2):

The "fade" that the datasheet mentions is fading between successive LEDs in DOT mode only.  It has nothing to do with how fast the LEDs respond to the incoming signal, but how the change in signal is represented.

For instance, an increase in input would be represented as:

```
.....
o....
O....
Oo...
oO...
.O...
.Oo..
.oO..
..O..
```

etc (. = off. o = dim, O = bright).

I think what you are wanting by your description is a slow fall-off of the signal, not a "fade".  That is where the display shows the latest peak value and then gradually drops down.

For that you would need a peak detector with sustaining circuit.  That would take the incoming signal and compare it to the current maximum value, and if higher then set the current maximum to the new value.  Over time the current maximum would reduce itself.  The bargraph module would then be representing this stored peak value instead of the actual signal value.

The "sustaining circuit" could be created with a capacitor with a bleed-off resistor (the time constant of the RC circuit defines the decay rate).  A circuit involving comparators could probably be built for the peak comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Scott K,

Sorry this arrives so late.  When I read your question it sounded like the responses were not addressing your question. If not maybe I got what you were asking.

From what you describe a simple method to try would be to take the moving signal that is coming into the LM3914 input and put it through a simple summing op-amp. On a second input to the opamp apply an oscillating signal (you could use one CD4046 to generate the signal and feed to multiple LM3914, if that is your design). Essentially the oscillator signal amplitude determines how much transitional blurring occurs between LED's as they switch on and off.

Some things to watch out for is careful layout and routing of the oscillator signal, as you do not want it to feed onto the actual signal source going into the LM3914. Hope this helps fellow electronics traveler.